# Node return image stored in sqlite blob

Tags: node.js, sqlite, blob, restify

I'm querying to an API using [Restify](https://github.com/restify/node-restify)
My SQLite database have a places table that has the following structure `(id INTEGER, name TEXT, image BLOB)`
I'm trying to output the response result as an image (the blob contains a jpeg image) but i haven't succeed so far.
In the browser after made the request i'm getting `The image 'http://localhost:8080/place/1 cannot be displayed because it contains errors`
I'm getting properly in the console the place name.

Here is my code:

```js
var restify = require('restify');

function respond(req, res, next) {
  var fs = require("fs");
  var file = "./data.db";
  var exists = fs.existsSync(file);

  var sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
  var db = new sqlite3.Database(file);

  db.get("SELECT id, name, image FROM places WHERE id = ?", req.params.uid, function(err, row){
    console.log(row.name);
    res.header('Content-Type', 'image/jpeg');
    res.end(row.image);
    db.close();
  });

  next();
}

var server = restify.createServer();

server.get('/place/:uid', respond);
server.listen(8080, function() {
  console.log('%s listening at %s', server.name, server.url);
});
```

**UPDATE:** The image is returned without troubles when i create the blob using the same [node-sqlite3](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3) library. If i create the blobs using Ruby or Go (the ones that i had tested) the `node-sqlite3` decoding doesn't work as expected.

Whats going on here? Any help appreciated.

Comment: You're closing the database with `db.close` before the query runs, since the query runs asynchronously. Move `db.close` to the end of the `db.get` callback.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo Done, still the same issue, i update the code with your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Use to VARCHAR  field and store in image as string then retrieve as byte array.
See below code that in you can store image and retrieve. without using blob.
that is easy method for you.

```
 Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
         ImageView imageView=(ImageView)this.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        getContentResolver().notifyChange(selectedImage, null);

        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        Bitmap bitmap;
        try {


            bitmap = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media
             .getBitmap(cr, selectedImage);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
            byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
            String encodedImageString = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);

            byte[] bytarray = Base64.decode(encodedImageString, Base64.DEFAULT);
            Bitmap bmimage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytarray, 0,
                    bytarray.length);

            myDb.execSQL("INSERT INTO imgtbl VALUES('"+encodedImageString+"');");
            Cursor c= myDb.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM imgtbl", null);

           c.moveToFirst();
           String img=c.getString(0);
           byte[] byarray = Base64.decode(img, Base64.DEFAULT);
           Bitmap bmimg = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byarray, 0,
                   byarray.length);

            ImageView iv=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img2);
            ImageView iv1=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img3);

            iv.setImageBitmap(bmimg);
            iv1.setImageBitmap(bmimg);


        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to load", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```